# Make a CSS header with all content vertical aligned

Tags: html, css, header, padding, innerhtml

I'm pretty new to CSS and need some help.

I'm currently making a site with one header in the top 100% width with it's content following the 960grid system.

Here's how I've made it so far, HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="header-inner">
/logo/
/nav/
/search/
</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#header { background: red; }
#header-inner { margin: auto; padding: 25px 0; width: 940px; }
```

I've used a clear-fix on the header-inner, and everything was working just fine. By inserting the logo as an IMG, it'd make sure that there was 25px space between the top and bottom of the logo, that way "defining" the height of the header.

Even after inserting the navigation as UL/LI elements, it was still working, however later when I added a search input everything messed up. The form tag seemed to give it a invisible border around the input, making it use more height than "needed".

The search input was also larger, so it obviously formed a new height.

I just wanted to know if there's a smart and effective way to make the header instead? Without having to remove the padding from the header-inner and having to define a padding-top and bottom on every single element in the header-inner parent

Comment: can you explain it more? i cannot fully understand your question

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by list

```
<ul>
  <li>logo</li>
  <li>nav</li>
  <li>search</li>
</ul>
```

you can  set the width  of li

Comment: isn't that a bit of an odd way to do it?

Comment: @user1833310 noop i dont think so